# Pattern by which you can determine that this is a FA2 contract, and not FA1.2

Tags: fa2, fa1.2, indexer, tzkt

i want to understand how tzkt indexer works. If there is some pattern by which you can determine that this is a fa2 contract, and not fa1.2? Maybe there is a prefix by which you can determine? I saw that fa2 has some specific bite code. I will be glad if someone gives me detailed information, thanks.

*From Baking Bad Telegram*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can distinguish between FA1.2 and FA2 by checking contract entrypoint semantics. For example: FA1.2 contract must implement approve entrypoint and FA2 must implement update_operators entrypoint.

Here you can find more information about FA1.2 and FA2 standards: [tzip-7](https://gitlab.com/tezos/tzip/-/blob/master/proposals/tzip-7/tzip-7.md#entrypoints) and [tzip-12](https://gitlab.com/tezos/tzip/-/blob/master/proposals/tzip-12/tzip-12.md#entrypoint-semantics)

*From Baking Bad Telegram*